# MySQL Copy Data Dump Script Not Working

Tags: mysql, sql, dump, transfer, workbench

So I'm trying to use a script generated by MySQL workbench to load a data dump into a MySQL database, however, I cannot seem to get rid of this error no matter what I do `"wbcopytables.exe doesn't exist in the supplied path. Please set 'wbcopytables_path' with the proper path(e.g. to Workbench binaries)"` The thing is, the path is set correctly (the default destination MySQL workbench is installed. This error is thrown in Powershell. When I try to run the script through the cmd line it simply closes and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, I've used the script in the past but it wasn't working after updating windows to 10 from 7. I had to do a fresh install of MySQL Workbench, so the bug might be in the latest version?  Not sure.  Here's the fix...

Remove...

```
if not ["%wbcopytables_path%"] == [] set "wbcopytables_path=%wbcopytables_path%"set "wbcopytables=%wbcopytables_path%wbcopytables.exe"
```

And replace with...

```
set "wbcopytables=%wbcopytables_path%\wbcopytables.exe"
```

worked for me, note sure if it's a "proper" fix, none the less, best of luck.